# Ensure unique tasks in ExectorService

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

I have a scenario wherein same Tasks get assigned multiple times to an `ExecutorService`. I want to avoid that, Is there a way to do it?

I have Tasks with a String constructor.

Task task1 = new Task ("A");
than I execute this task
executor.execute (task1);

Then I create another task with same string.

Task task2 = new Task ("A");

Lets say I cannot avoid this from happening.

Now I execute this task.

executor.execute (task2).

I want only one of these tasks to be executed, since both tasks are similar in nature.

How?

Comment: Writing code to prevent it? A non-specific answer to a non-specific question.

Comment: Can you please explain using some code..got nothing to add to my question here..

Comment: You haven't said how tasks are assigned. You haven't defined how you determine whether two tasks are the same. You basically haven't told us _anything_.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Edited my answer pls check..Its 4:30 am in India..you can understand my situation..

Comment: Sorry, how does telling us the time in India affect anything?

Comment: Please answer if you know..

Answer (score 0):

At first, I would have implemented a queue interface and passed it to the executor service. My implementation would be using a hashset to hold the memory, next to a regular collection to hold the tasks as the queue requires. Adding to my queue therefore would have involved checking the hashset first. Maybe a linkedhashset rolling off eldest entries...

**However, the executorservice submit() doesn't fully rely on the queue.** See the javadoc of ThreadPoolExecutor. The queue could refuse the task, but the executor could spawn a thread instead and still accept the task. Besides, that implies you could intervene in the executor's construction anyway.

So, presuming control on the executor's class, it seems you must extend an executorservice and have the knowledge there instead of a in a custom queue. You only need to override submit() and throw the rejection exception.

Of course, this reveals the rejection to the submitter. You should deal with that gracefully. You cannot hide this fact because you cannot return a Future if there was no submission. Unless you wire up the old Future to the new one (your knowledge hashmap contains Futures). This may cause difficulties though since every Future has a 'done' state and is cancel-able... Your own Future would be delegating to the original Futures. I think task rejection is simpler.